# How does HAWQ design cache to improve the speed of getting data?

Tags: postgresql, caching, hawq

For PostgreSQL, there is a shared memory to cache data for performance improvement. As a OLAP database, how does HAWQ cache data? What's the similarity and difference of the design comparing to PostgreSQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For cache management on actual data part, HAWQ just leverages what PostgreSQL has done.

For cache on metadata part, there is a process on HAWQ master node, named "DFS Metadata Cache process". This process will cache the block information for the HDFS files of HAWQ table.